# Understanding what typedef HRESULT(__stdcall* endScene)(IDirect3DDevice9* pDevice) does

Tags: c++, typedef

I found this piece of code and i cant understand what it means and what it does:

```
typedef HRESULT(__stdcall* endScene)(IDirect3DDevice9* pDevice);
endScene pEndScene;
```

I would appreciate any clues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is declaring an alias for a function pointer type, and then declaring a variable of that type.

It is declaring a type named `endScene`, which is a pointer to a function that takes in an `IDirect3DDevice9*` as input, uses the `__stdcall` calling convention, and returns an `HRESULT` as output.

And then it is declaring a variable named `pEndScene` of type `endScene`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, what confused me is the first part HRESULT(__stdcall* endScene), it was kinda confusing, and i actually had to look up some articles to "partially" understand function pointers along with ur answer